# How to have a class which can only be instantiated by another specific class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to have a class that can only be instantiated by another class. I know I have to make the `constructor` private otherwise everyone can instantiate it.

```
class Root private constructor() {
}

class RootMaker: Application() {
    fun createRoot() = Root()
} // but this doesn't work because Root's constructor is private
```

one workaround is to make the `maker` class, the inner class of the `Root` class.

```
class Root private constructor() {

    class RootMaker: Application() {
        fun createRoot() = Root()
    } 
}
```

but I really don't want to do this because the maker class is my `application` class in android. so what is the better way?

Comment: You could make the constructor `protected` and the `RootMaker` a child of `Root` class

Comment: I can't do that because `RootMaker` is already child of `application' class

Comment: What is the reasoning behind your request, because I do have to wonder if this represents an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) type question.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter the `RootMaker` is actually my `CustomApplication` class and the `Root` class is my `CompositionRoot` class for creating instances of other classes for dependency injection. I want to create an instance of the `CompositionRoot` class in the `Application` class, so when the app is started one instance will be created, and every other class need to get the instance from the `Application` class not directly creating new instances. that is the reason

Comment: Short of inspecting the stack trace of the calling thread, and assuming that `Root` itself must be public, I believe the best you can do is make the constructor `internal` and just make sure never to instantiate the class anywhere else in your module. Though I suppose, given your reasoning, you could make `Root` responsible for holding the singleton instance.

Comment: thanks @Slaw but I only have one module and `internal` does not help. I spouse this should have a solution and "make sure never to instantiate the class anywhere else" is not a proper way of doing it, what if this was a helper class or a library? you can't expect that your users don't instantiate the classes that you give them access to!

Comment: Neither Java nor Kotlin have a direct mechanism to enforce "only this class can instantiate this other class". The best you can do, while not resorting to hacks, is to strategically use visibility modifiers. And Kotlin annoyingly does not support package-private visibility. Your options include: (1) Document the usage requirements and make sure to use the API correctly, (2) inspect the stack trace to check the caller, (3) use reflection to instantiate, or (4) use the "friend accessor" pattern (not sure it this pattern works in Kotlin). There may be some other approach I'm missing.

Comment: Here's an example of the "friend accessor" pattern in Java: http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/APIDesignPatterns:FriendPackages

Comment: @Slaw thank you you were really helpful but unfortunately, I don't know how to do any of that :D especially #3 use reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one instance of an object you can use [`object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html#object-declarations) keyword in Kotlin. It implements `Singleton` pattern:

```
class App : Application {
    
    val root = Root

}

object Root {
    fun createObject(): Any {}
}
```

Now we can access to one instance of `Root` class either by a property in `App` class or via `Root` class: `Root.createObject()`

UPDATE:

To implement a singleton that only one specific class has access to, we can use an interface and hide its implementation in that specific class (the **maker** class):

```
interface IRoot {
    // ... methods of creation different objects for dependency injection
}

class App : Application {

    val root: IRoot = Root

    // hide implementation of `IRoot` interface in `App` class
    private object Root : IRoot {

        // ... implementation of methods of creation different objects for dependency injection
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is I want only one class to be able to get the instance, I'm not asking for singleton here. it is a singleton that only one specific class has access to its instance

Comment: I assume by `Any()` you mean `Root()`, the class that I want to make an instance of. so how this pattern helps to prevent other classes to create `Root()` directly. the only way I know is to make its constructor private, and by doing that the Interface you suggested can't create the class too

Comment: No, in the comments you mentioned "the Root class is my CompositionRoot class for creating instances of other classes for dependency injection", so by `Any` I meant any object you want to create. Let me remove it so as not to confuse you.

Comment: thanks this is actually what I needed. and instead of constructor one can use invoke() function on the interface